# Only evaluate parts of a condition when the corresponding flag is set

Tags: javascript, if-statement

For example, I have `flag1`, `flag2`, `flag3`,..., `flagN` as boolean values for flags.

I need to write an if statement like this: If `flagK` is `false`, then turn off the "K" part of the condition:

```
if (condition0 && (flag1 && condition1) && (flag2 && condition2) ... && (flagN && conditionN))
{
   // do something
} 

// For example, if flag 2 is false then the condition should only be:
if (condition0 && (flag1 && condition1) && ... && (flagN && conditionN))
{
   //do something}
}
```

Particularly, given an example like this (for demo only not my real problem):

```
const divby2 = false; //if this is false, then ignore the **i%2 === 0** below
const divby3 = true;
const divby4 = true;
const divby5 = true;
//......const divbyN....

const array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,42,45,241,526]
 
array.forEach((i) => {
    if(i >= 0 && (divby2 && i%2 === 0) && (divby3 && i%3 === 0)) {
      console.log(i) // output here should be 3,6,9,12 instead of nothing
    }
  }
)
```

Example Result:
[image: Example Result]

Comment: Are you sure about your truth table ? There are multiple occurences for some numbers. Or maybe I did not understand your question ?

Comment: ah thank you for pointing out that, let me update
@Seblor btw the truth table is true, that is what i wanted, if divby3 is false mean you don't have to make sure that the value is divide by 3

Comment: Don't you just have to change the parts like this? `!flag1 || condition1`

Comment: @Jenny O'Reilly Wow it really works well ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term you are looking for is "short-circuit" similar to the way in real electronic circuit if some part is not working you just short circuit it and by pass flow to rest

```
 if(i >= 0 && ( divby2 && i%2 === 0 || !divby2) && (divby3 && i%3 === 0))
```

In this case if you are wanting that filtered number should be divisible by 2 that time you set `divby2` = `true`

And when you just want to ignore and don't care about the divisibility by 2 you set `divby2` = `false`

In pseudo

```
(is-checking-for-divby-2? AND is-current-number-divby-2?) OR (NOT is-checking-for-divby-2?)
```

As soon as you are not checking for divby 2 you make this logic fragment true so it won't affect evaulation of the follolwing logic fragments

And..Why should you bother making this fragments TRUE?

Because you `AND`ing them

Similarly you can go for `divby3`, `divby4` ...

Comment: If I use ( i%2 === 0 ||  !divby2 ) it still gives the same output as your solution. Is there really any difference in these cases? Is it really neccessary to put the (divby2 && i%2 === 0 ||  !divby2 ) instead of  ( i%2 === 0 ||  !divby2 )

Comment: No need to put they both are equivalent. If you see the meaning of it `i%2 === 0` it goes  _"is the current number divisible by 2?"_, suppose it's not. Then you look at ` !divby2` it says _"I'll always lie"_ . Now ask yourself "If `i`(current number)  is not divisible by 2 and I'm not interested in divisibility by 2 (ie `divby2` is `false`) shouldn't the whole(||'rd) fragment pass?"  conversely if I'm interested in divisibility by 2 (ie `divby2` is `true`) but `i` is not divisible should the fragment fail? think like `!divby2` is done and evaluated to false and now all rests on `i%2 === 0`

Answer (score 1):

I would have an object with your conditions, and then filter out the functions you don't want to run, and then just reduce the object to a single function which runs all of the enabled functions:

```js
const conditions = {
    divby2: i => i % 2 === 0,
    divby3: i => i % 3 === 0,
};

const enabled = {
    divby2: false, //if this is false, then need to ignore the **i%2 === 0** below
    divby3: true
}

const enabledConditions = (i) => {
    return Object.entries(conditions).filter(
        ([key, value]) => enabled[key]
    ).reduce((carry, [_, condition]) => {
          return condition(i) && carry
    }, i !== false);

}
//......const divbyN....
const array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,42,45,241,526]
 

array.forEach((i) => {
    if(i >= 0 && enabledConditions(i)){
      console.log(i) //output here should be 3,6,9,12 instead of nothing
    }
  }
)
```

Comment: This is truly a masterpiece one